# Rearrange TableView Cells With NsMutualArray Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, nsmutablearray

Im trying to add this function to my favoritesTab but I'm struggling a bit at the moment.
What I'm trying to achieve is so i will be able to move cells & delete them.

## Here is what i currently have:

```
   import UIKit
    
    
        class FavoritesViewController : UITableViewController {

  //declaring the array :

let Fav: NSMutableArray = []
        Fav.addObject(barImage)
        Fav.addObject(barName)
         Fav.addObject(streetName)
        favorite.addObject(Fav)
        
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
                
                return true
                
            }
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
                let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FavoriteCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FavoriteCell
                
                let Fav = favorite.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSMutableArray
                Cell.FavoriteName!.text = Fav.objectAtIndex(1) as? String
                Cell.FavoritePhoto?.image = Fav.objectAtIndex(0) as? UIImage
                Cell.FavoriteStreet!.text = Fav.objectAtIndex(2) as? String
                
                return Cell
                
            }
            
            override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath targetIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            var sourceIndex = sourceIndexPath.row
            var targetIndex = targetIndexPath.row
            if sourceIndex != targetIndex {
                var item = favorite[sourceIndex]
                favorite.removeAtIndex(favorite.indexOf(item)!)
                favorite.insert(item, atIndex: targetIndex)
            }
        }
        
            override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
            {
                if(favorite.count == 0){
                    return 0
                }else if(favorite.count != 0){
                    return favorite.count
                }
                return 0
            }
```

i always get errors at `func moveRowAt` specifically on insert and remove... probably cause I'm using `nsmutualarray`.

and i need help so i can be able to complete this feature

thanks in advance

## Edit:

**Errors i get:**

[image]

Comment: "i always get errors at func moveRowAt specifically on insert and remove" What errors exactly ? What's your code with `moveRowAt`?

Comment: Just a sec i will update my code.

Comment: @Larme code updated

Comment: You are using an "old" version of Swift, does XCode prompte any suggestion when you try to type favorite.remove...? Maybe `removeObjectAtIndex()` and `insertObject(at:)` or something similar?

Comment: @Larme No,Just straight shows off these errors.And yes i do use swift 2.3

Comment: @Newbie Questions how have you declared your array?

Comment: @TusharSharma Updated The code.

Comment: @Newbie Questions try like this var fav: NSMutableArray =  []

Comment: Do you mean `var Fav: [NSMutableArray]= []` you are missing a [ ?@TusharSharma

Comment: @Newbie Questions yes exactly sorry for that.

Comment: well i guess it might work without it as well.

Comment: @TusharSharma Yea when i add the `[ ]` i actually get errors it has nothing to do with `addObject`

Comment: @TusharSharma i still get the errors i show in the pictures tho...

Comment: and instead of using removeAtIndex try using array.removeObjectAtIndex(index) with var array: NSMutableArray = []

Comment: but if i don't use the array I'm using to populate the data how it will work?

Comment: This is array only.add objects in it.

Comment: Can we continue talking in a chat that will be more comfortable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137851/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-newbie-questions).